# How to fetch an Multi value Embedded Schema Image field using razor?

Tags: razormediator

I would like to fetch an imagefield from the multivalue Embedded Schema Field. Here is my code.

```
@foreach(var banners in Fields.Banners)
{
  @if(banners.RDBannerSchema.WebBannerImage.ID !=null)
      <img src="@banners.RDBannerSchema.WebBannerImage.ID" alt="" />
      <div class="blockCont">
        <h2>@blocks.Fields.Title</h2>
        <div class="overCont">
             @blocks.Fields.Description
             <a href="javascript:;">@blocks.Fields.LinkText</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
}
```

When I render this page  I got error Message.

> `System.Collections.Generic.List<Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Models.ComponentModel>`' does not contain a definition for 'ID']

In Anguilla

Answer (score 2):

I Found the answer for this issue. Thanks http://codedweapon.com/

```
@foreach (var embeddedFields in Fields.SomeEmbeddedFields) {
  <div class="@(embeddedFields.IsLast ? "last" : String.Empty)">@embeddedFields.Address (@embeddedFields.ZipCode)</div>
}
```

http://codedweapon.com/tag/templating/

Answer (score 0):

You can fatch the image value like this
@if (Component.Fields.thumbnail != null)
{
   @Component.Fields.thumbnail.Fields.alt
}